# Making a Restful Request to Solr in Visual Studio giving (Service unavailable error: 503)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rest, solr, webrequest

I am making a Restful get request to an instance of Solr, to retrieve the status of the instance, the uri I am using has been checked to be correct and gives the expected response through the web browser and postman.

Has anyone had issues making restful requests to Solr, as it seems weird that I can make the request through the browser but not through visual studio?

Comment: Can you add samples of your request? Can you monitor the request done by your code and provide the http response code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Solr and Visual Studio is there a reason why you are not using SolrNet?

SolrNet is a .Net client to work with Solr that makes development faster:
https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet